# boost program options changes data when it reads from command line (is it a bug in boost?)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I have this code in boost::program options:

```
("output_path,o", po::value< std::string >(&outputPath)->implicit_value(""), "path to where the output should be created.")
```

and on command line I have:

```
-o "C:\My Data\ImagesWithDifferentResolution\"
```

when boost options fill outputPath with data, I am getting this value in the variable:

```
 C:\My Data\ImagesWithDifferentResolution"
```

note the extra quote at the end of path.

How can I fix it?

## EDIT 1

To be clear it is a bug in boost. I know that I should escape the strings when I am compiling my code, but this is the way that boost program options works and extracting input data from command line.

So to explain a bit more:

My program called testPrg.exe and I am trying to call it in the following way:

```
 testprg.exe -o "C:\My Data\ImagesWithDifferentResolution\"
```

which is correct and my user should be able to do this. There is no need to escape the \ on command line.

But the boost program options, mistakenly convert the last \" into a escape value.

test application which shows the bug:

```
main()
{
    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    std::string outputPath;
    desc.add_options()
    ("output_path,o", po::value< std::string >(&outputPath)->implicit_value(""), "path to where the output should be created.")
                ;
    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc).positional(p).run(), vm);
    po::notify(vm);
    std::cout<<outputPath <<std::endl;
 }
```

compile the cod with boost 1.58 and run it as explained above and inspect the output.

Comment: You are escaping " with \, escape \ with another \ and it will work. Are other arguments not affected? It would be strange. You want: `-o "C:\My Data\ImagesWithDifferentResolution\\"`. Anyway it is a good idea to always escape \.

Comment: `C:\\My Data\\Images`... etc actually

Comment: @PiotrJaszkowski: note that it is program option that comes form command line and I can not escape it! I think It is a bug in boost!

Comment: @mans: That is not a bug in boost, it's a feature. It is up to user to properly escape command-line arguments. For example you would like to pass an argument like this: `--mom "He said: \"NO!\""` Without escaping it would be impossible and you cannot expect boost to know what you want actually to do.

Comment: @PiotrJaszkowski Thanks for explanation. Is there any way that I can configure boost not to do the escaping and just pass me the data? For example i don't want to escape on path data, so I want to stop it from doing escape on this option.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? MSVC, MinGW or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug in Boost.Program_options; it is the expected behavior of the Microsoft C/C++ startup code provided by your compiler. That is, the `\"` has already been converted to `"` by the time it is passed to `main` in `argv`.

From [Parsing C Command-Line Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx) in the Visual Studio 2015 reference:

> A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash, `\"`, is interpreted as a literal double quotation mark (`"`).
>
> ```
> Command-Line Input | argv[1] | argv[2] | argv[3]
> -------------------+---------+---------+---------
> "ab\"c" "\\" d     | ab"c    | \       | d
> ```

A possible workaround might be to call `GetCommandLine` to get `lpCommandLine` and [pass that to `split_winmain`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#idp343316480) (though that might have the same behavior as the Microsoft startup code) or split the command line yourself.